How do you determine the distance traveled by an object at runtime?
Is there a way to use geometry nodes to record the distance traveled by an object? Similar to an odometer in a car while driving. The distance/value traveled should be output for further actions. I have tried it with "Accumulation Field" node and the vector "Object Info -->Location", but it does not work as soon as the location vector gets negative values.
One possibility would be to calculate the distance traveled from frame to frame with the Location Vector itself and add it up. However, this would also require the location data from the previous frame. Does anyone know of a way to do this? Unfortunately, I have not found anything in the Geometry Nodes.
Are there other possible solutions?
Thank you.

I've made a velocity/acceleration/distance meter in GN, which works with animated objects and in realtime while the animation is running, maybe check this out: How to measure velocity and acceleration in real time using geometry nodes in Blender? It's not made with the latest version, but it still works in 4.2 (I'm just not sure if some things might be more convenient to do with latest nodes).
